# Why couldn't we use an object of std::initializer_list to initialize an array?

Tags: c++

Please consider the example bellow first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <set>

int main(){
   std::initializer_list il1={1,2,3,4,5}; 
   std::initializer_list il2{1,2,3,4,5}; 
                                    
    std::vector<int> v1 = il1;  //this work - by means of COPY 
    std::set<int> s1 = il1;     //this work - by means of COPY

    std::array<int, 5> a1 = {1,2,3,4,5};  //this work
    std::array<int, 5> a2 = il1;      //this didn't work? - not compatable ?
    int array1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};          //this work
    int array2[5] = il2;              //this didn't work? - not compatable ?                               
}
```

Why couldn't we use an object of std::initializer_list to initialize an array in the example?

I get this error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:15:29: error: conversion from 'std::initializer_list<int>' to non-scalar type 'std::array<int, 5>' requested
   15 |     std::array<int, 5> a2 = il1;      //this didn't work? - not compatable ?
      |                             ^~~
<source>:17:21: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
   17 |     int array2[5] = il2;              //this didn't work? - not compatable ?
      |
```

And is there any particular difference between: il1 (in std::initializer_list il1={1,2,3,4,5}; ) and {1,2,3,4,5} alone?

Comment: Because both plain arrays and `std::array` are *aggregates* and those can only be initialized with [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It's not possibly to use other unrelated objects for aggregate initialization. Plain arrays can't even be copy-initialized (so e.g. `int array3[5] = array1;` is not possible). `std::array` allows copy-semantics though, of another `std::array` object of the exact same type.

Comment: whats the error? It contains valuable information. Compiler errors nowadays tell you so much about why and sometimes even how to fix

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai "no suitable-user conversion" error :D

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question. Indeed, there is no suitable user-conversion. Thats the reason for the error. So your question boils down to: Whats the difference between arrays and `set` and `vector`? Once you understood why it works for `set` and `vector` you will see why it doesnt for `array`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai What do you think about the answer in it's edited shape? Should I undelete?

Comment: @TedLyngmo my critic was only that it can be misread as your `intitializer_list` resembling `std::initializer_list` but it does not. I think it doesnt really matter what `std::initializer_list` is, arrays just have no matching constructor (and there is also no other conversion)

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that the literal `{1,2,3,4,5}` is *not* an `initializer_list`, but it can be converted to one.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I also realized that my mental model is too simplified to be of much use. I'll let it be deleted.

Comment: wait a sec... only now I realize that the error you included in the question is unrelated to your actual question. "...does not name a type" can be caused by a missing include, but I cannot reproduce that error with your code: https://godbolt.org/z/9Ksa4jMhE only when compiled as <c++11 that error appears. Please clarify the question

Comment: if you do get that error then nothing "works" in your code

Comment: no. You removed it again. Thats not fixing. A question about code that causes a compiler error should contain the compiler error. I was just inattentive when I though you did include the compiler error. The thing is that you could have faced the error you did post. But you didnt, and we cannot know unless you tell us. Nevermind, it is settled. Frankly, at this point I dont care what error you faced anymore, but I added the one I got.

Comment: oh right, somebody has fixed it for me already I guess

Comment: thanks @463035818_is_not_an_ai , so much misfortune for a small village :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) has a initializer list constructor

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

(`constexpr` since C++20)

[`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set) has a initializer list constructor

```
set( std::initializer_list<value_type> init, const Compare& comp = Compare(), const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

(and since C++14 another delegating constructor)

`std::array` has no user defined constructor (read "user" as "not compiler generated"). It is an aggregate.

This

```
std::array<int, 5> a1 = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
int array1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

is [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Here `{1,2,3,4,5}` is an *ordinary initializer list* (thats how cppreference calls it, not sure if thats the official term). It is not a `std::initializer_list`.

There are special rules when a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is constructed. For details I refer you to the link. For example:

```
std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5};
```

This calls the above constructor. A `std::initializer_list` is created from `{1,2,3,4,5}` but only because `std::vector` has a constructor that accepts a `std::intializer_list`.

PS: If you wonder why the rules are a bit odd, recall that before c++11 it was not possible to make something like `std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5};` work out of the box, while `int array1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};` was there long before. Something new had to be added and thats `std::initializer_list` and some special rules when they are created.

PPS: Rarely if ever you need to explicitly construct a `std::initializer` as you do in your code. Sloppy speaking they are just the glue between syntax, `{1,2,3,4,5}`, and a constructor with parameter of some *special* type.

Comment: *"read "user" as "..., not supplied by the standard library code"* I believe "supplied by standard library code" does count as user-defined, otherwise nothing in `std::` could have user-defined constructors, and everything would be an aggregate. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks well spotted, there was a "not" to much. I meant to write "read "user" as " (not compiler generated) / (supplied by the library code)"", but simply removing it is more clear I guess